# Magento 2 Advanced Reports 404 page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, api, advanced-reporting

How to fix 404 page in Magento 2.2 - 2.3.4 versions Advanced reports? If you see the status pending in the configurations, and the user for advanced reports is absent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all create manually a new Reports user, open :

```
System->Extensions->Integrations
```

Check is a user with the name "Magento Analytics user" is there. If not please do the next steps:

- press New Integration button
- paste the name - "New Integration", into the name input.
- in the field "Your Password" type the current admin password
- at the left tab, press the "API" tab.
- In the "Resource Access" dropdown, select the "All" option, and in the next step press
  "continue" (do not change any keys, tokens,etc.) Press save.
  Clean/flush caches.

Now you can check your current integration status in the :

```
Stores->Configurations->General->Advanced reports.
```

If the Status is enabled -> everything is fine (check it in 5-10 mins). If it is pending, go to prev. step and press in the grid "reauthorize" and check again your current status. enter image description here

And now you should wait for 24 hrs for a report generation. But here we have a small lifehack, just follow these steps:

Go to the Magento root dir via ssh or terminal: Download the latest stable N98-Magerun phar-file from the file-server:

```
wget https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun2.phar
```

add "run" permissions:

```
chmod +x ./n98-magerun2.phar
```

and after that just simply run:

```
./n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:run analytics_collect_data
```

After these last steps, please wait ~10-15 mins and press "Go to advanced reports" button at the right top corner in the Magento dashboard.

*If it was helpful, please vote up! With love from Ukraine <3*

Comment: it's give me an Error :
"Directory "/tmp/analytics/tmp" cannot be created Warning!mkdir(): Permission denied"

Comment: just create this dir /tmp/analytics/tmp, coz looks like you haven't permissions to do that via PHP

Comment: I already have created this dir on root also in var folder. but same error.

Comment: use "chmod " command with the right file owner

Comment: Everything Done, But still not showing advanced reports, Give 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Advanced Reporting extension username is "Advanced Reporting" and NOT "Advanced Reporting user". I found on deleting the latter and creating a new user as in the former resulted in Advanced Reporting working after the next processing cycle.